# R For Loop with Certain conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a dataframe (surveillance) with many variables (villages, houses, weeks). I want to eventually do a time-series analysis.

Currently for each village, there are between 1-183 weeks, each of which has several houses associated. I need the following: each village to have a single data point at each week. Thus, I need to sum up a third variable.

Example:
Village   Week         House       Affect
 A        3             7           12
 B        6             3           0
 C        6             2           2
 A        3             9           1
 A        5             8           0
 A        5             2           8
 C        7             19          0
 C        7             2           1
I tried this and failed. How do I ask R to only sum observations with the same village and week value?

```
for (i in seq(along=surveillance)) {
    if (surveillance$village== surveillance$village& surveillance$week== surveillance$week)
    {surveillance$sumaffect <- sum(surveillance$affected)}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please consider posting a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you post  `dput(surveillance)` on 10 rows of the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

No need for loop. Use `ddply` or similar

```
library(plyr)
Village = c("A","B","C","A","A","A","C","C")
Week = c(3,6,6,3,5,5,7,7)
Affect = c(12,0,2,1,0,8,0,1)

df = data.frame(Village,Week,Affect)
View(df)

result = ddply(df,.(Village,Week),summarise, val = sum(Affect))
View(result)
```

DF:

```
    Village Week    Affect
1   A   3   12
2   B   6   0
3   C   6   2
4   A   3   1
5   A   5   0
6   A   5   8
7   C   7   0
8   C   7   1
```

Result:

```
    Village Week    val
1   A   3   13
2   A   5   8
3   B   6   0
4   C   6   2
5   C   7   1
```

Comment: While that worked perfectly for the example code, it still seems to require me to type in each entry. There are 115,232 observations in my actual dataframe.

Comment: surveillance <- read.csv("SurveillenceHouseholdWeek.csv", header=T, dec=".", sep=",")

Comment: OK. So what do you mean by "type in each entry"? If you still want to sum `Affect`, you don't need to type in anything else.

Comment: Sorry I misread the code. I do get the following error though: In cbind(Weekct = 1:177, comunidad = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)  

I'm new to R so it may a painfully easy error to solve. Thanks for patience

Comment: Reproducible input needed. Pls run `dput`

Answer (score 0):

The function `aggregate` will do what you need.

```
dfs <- '  Village Week House Affect
1       A    3     7     12
2       B    6     3      0
3       C    6     2      2
4       A    3     9      1
5       A    5     8      0
6       A    5     2      8
7       C    7    19      0
8       C    7     2      1
'
df <- read.table(text=dfs)
```

Then the aggregation

```
> aggregate(Affect ~ Village + Week , data=df, sum)
  Village Week Affect
1       A    3     13
2       A    5      8
3       B    6      0
4       C    6      2
5       C    7      1
```

This is an example of a split-apply-combine strategy; if you find yourself doing this often, you should investigate the `dplyr` (or `plyr`, its ancestor) or `data.table` as alternatives to quickly doing this sort of analysis.

EDIT: updated to use `sum` instead of `mean`